# Defing a var with a max value.

Tags: javascript

Is a simple one liner to do the following:

```
var asbMax = max
if (asbMax > 100000) 
  asbMax = 100000
```

Other languages allow you do this in one line and I have wondering if Javascript has a way to do this as well.

Comment: You could also do `var asbMax = Math.min(max, 100000);` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)

Comment: @Ian You should post that as an alternative answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can definitely use ternary operators, another option for your specific scenario is to use `Math.min`. Here's an example:

```
var asbMax = Math.min(max, 100000);
```

This method returns the smallest number out of the arguments passed to it. So here, if `max` is less than `100000`, it will return `max`. But if `max` is bigger than `100000`, it will return `100000`.

**Reference:**

- `Math.min`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min

Comment: I kinda like this more.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can use the ternary operator:

```
var asbMax = max > 100000 ? 100000 : max;
```

As a suggestion to prevent further typos on the allowed maximum:

```
var allowedMax = 100000;

var asbMax = max > allowedMax ? allowedMax : max;
```

See: [MDN – Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make sure `foo` doesn't go above a `123`, there are a few ways to do it:

```
// the way you have
if (foo > 123) {
  foo = 123;
}

// using ternary operators
foo = foo > 123 ? 123 : foo;

// using Math.min
foo = Math.min(foo, 123);

// using a method from http://sugarjs.com/
var minimumValue = 0;
foo = foo.clamp(minimumValue, 123);

// using https://github.com/hughsk/clamp for Node.js
var clamp = require("clamp");
var minimumValue = 0;
foo = clamp(foo, minimumValue, 123);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var asbMax = (max > 100000) ? 100000 : max;
```